# inserting dataframe into Oracle Datebase using pyodbc: Error: ('HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!')

Tags: sql, oracle, pandas, insert, pyodbc

I am trying to insert a dataframe into an Oracle Database using pyodbc. My code looks as follows:

```
pyodbc.pooling = False
conn_str = (
    r'DRIVER={Oracle in OraClient12Home1};'
    r'UID=***;'
    r'PWD=***;'
    ...
    ...)

conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str, autocommit=True)
curs = conn.cursor()

curs.executemany('INSERT INTO TABLE.NAME(AUFTRAGNR, TYPNR, MENGE, CNT, LL_NR, LL_NR2, DATE) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', my_df.values.tolist())
curs.commit()
curs.close()
```

One row of the dataframe I am trying to input is:

`['0010930795', '231', 1, 1, nan, nan, Timestamp('2019-06-07 09:41:03')]`

The data types of the columns as shown in Access are:

`AUFTRAGNR:`   Short Text
`TYPNR:` Short Text
`MENGE:` Number
`CNT:` Number
`LL_NR:` Short Text
`LL_NR2:` Short Text
`DATE:` Date/Time

The error I get is:

Error: ('HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!')

Since the error message is not very descriptive and I don't see any obvious mistakes in my code, I don't really know how to approach this. What are the possible causes for this error?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you insert rows if they do not contain `nan` values?

Comment: It seems that the problem is not the `nan`'s. but the integer columns `MENGE` and  `CNT` ...when i try to insert data points individually  the error for those columns is:  

'Invalid parameter type.  param-index=0 param-type=numpy.int64', 'HY105'

Comment: You could try using SQLAlchemy's [Oracle dialect](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/oracle.html) along with pandas' [to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) method. That might help avoid problems with incompatible types between numpy and the database access layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did eventually figure out twhat the problem was. The data type `Number` defined in the database refers to **floats** not **integers** so the following input will work:

`['0010930795', '231', 1.0, 1.0, nan, nan, Timestamp('2019-06-07 09:41:03')]`